# WordPress ignores line breaks in user description

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem where WordPress isn't showing line breaks when I echo the user description. The text shows in one line.

I'm using this line of code to show the user description:

```
<?php $user = get_user_by( 'slug', 'admin' ); echo  $user->description ?>
```

Any idea what could be causing the problem and how to get WordPress to show the line breaks in the user description? Adding `<br />` to the description box on user profile settings page doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could do something like this:

```
echo  nl2br($user->description);
```

To optimize things, you could plug it up so that your user description saves the string using `nl2br` when saved in the database.